agent with actiongroup in bedrock using python cdk - "CreateAgentRequest caught an error. Failed to retrieve Agent with ID:
I am trying to create an agent with bedrock and encountering the following error:
AWS::Bedrock::Agent     | LunarCfnAgent1 Resource handler returned message: "CreateAgentRequest caught an error. Failed to retrieve Agent with ID: QF0MJDJ1ZJ and Version: DRAFT because it doesn't exist. Retry the request with a different resource identifier. (Service: BedrockAgent, Status Code: 404, Request ID: 4fac1bbe-70ab-4b41-b6eb-2857bae4b47f)".
Please help if you know of a way to overcome.
